# ASP MVC Retrieving data in one single view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I am a bit confused about how to show the data I need in my View. On the first page I want to show the newly added products and the categories. So far I managed to get the main categories and send them to the view. Below is what I did so far.

```
HomeController.cs

public ActionResult Index()
{
List<CategoriesViewModel> mainCategories = (from cat in db.Categories
                                  where cat.ParentID == null
                                  orderby cat.Name
                                  select new CategoriesViewModel { Name = cat.Name}).ToList();

return View(mainCategories);
}

Categories.cs

public class CategoriesViewModel
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsDBContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<CategoriesViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

Index.cshtml

@model List<Website.Models.CategoriesViewModel>
...
<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model) {
<li><a href="#">@item.Name</a></li>
}
</ul>
```

Now if I want to show the top products too, what should be done? Any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean top products?

Comment: Show for example some random 10 products from the database.

Comment: I don't understand your problem very well, I see that inside your view you already have the data shown, so what is the problem?

Comment: I have a list of categories, and now I need a list of products too. I don't know if it's ok to just extend my current model and return 2 lists to the view.

Comment: Can I make the assumption that the categories contain the products or not?

Comment: Yes, the categories contain products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how this can be done without explicitly having to create another model since in your case the data that your model contains is linked by a parent-child relationship (category is a parent of product).

Here's a short snippet to help you get the idea.

```
@foreach(var item in Model) {
    // do specific formatting for the way you want to render each category
    foreach(var product in Model.Products){
        // do show product in a way that you prefer
     }
}
```

Just for future reference :
In the case when you don't have this parent-child relationship : you can solve this problem with the creation of a class that contains both of the classes that you would like to use in your model. Although, in my opinion you should avoid doing that.